# Docking div displayed as inline-block vertically at the top in a parent div

Tags: html, css

I have created the following fiddle to illustrate the problem http://jsfiddle.net/spjvo6g2/

How to dock the child divs such as activelist to vertically align to the top portion of the parent div

```
<div class="lists">
        <div id="activelist">
            <label for="">To buy</label>
            <ul>
                <li class="activeitem">brocoli</li>
                <li class="activeitem">spinach</li>
                <li class="activeitem">mushrooms</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="deferredlist">
            <label for="">Deffered</label>
            <ul>
                <li class="deferreditem">shoes</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="completedlist">
            <label for="">Done</label>
            <ul>
                <li class="doneitem">bread</li>
                <li class="doneitem">milk</li>
                <li class="doneitem">popcorn</li>
                <li class="doneitem">chicken</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


.lists div
{
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 4em;     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.lists div{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 4em;  
    vertical-align:top; <-- add this
}
```

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/spjvo6g2/2/

```css
.lists div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 4em;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="lists">
  <div id="activelist">
    <label for="">To buy</label>
    <ul>
      <li class="activeitem">brocoli</li>
      <li class="activeitem">spinach</li>
      <li class="activeitem">mushrooms</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="deferredlist">
    <label for="">Deffered</label>
    <ul>
      <li class="deferreditem">shoes</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="completedlist">
    <label for="">Done</label>
    <ul>
      <li class="doneitem">bread</li>
      <li class="doneitem">milk</li>
      <li class="doneitem">popcorn</li>
      <li class="doneitem">chicken</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```